# Javascript buttons, prevent mouse double click

Tags: javascript, css, html, carousel

I have two buttons that use Javascript to call their function which controls a carousel and some other actions.

I'd simply like to disable the ability of the user to doubleclick the button.

Here is my code:

```
var onRightArrow = function(e) {
    //alert("Right");
    if (unitCtr<=unitTotal) {
        unitCtr++;
        TweenLite.to(productTxt, 0.2, {y: "-="+unitHeight });
        TweenLite.to(productImg, 0.2, {y: "-="+unitHeight });
    }
    hideArrows();
}, onLeftArrow = function(e) {
    //alert("Left");
    if (unitCtr>1) {
        unitCtr--;
        TweenLite.to(productTxt, 0.2, {y: "+="+unitHeight });
        TweenLite.to(productImg, 0.2, {y: "+="+unitHeight });
    }
    hideArrows();
}

arrowRight.addEventListener('click', onRightArrow, false);
arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', onLeftArrow, false);
```

I'm aware of the dblclick line of code but not exactly sure how to apply to disable the double click action from the mouse.

When the user doubleclicks now, it misplaces the positioning of the elements in the carousel which is why I want to remove the ability of the dblclick to affect the button.

Thanks in advance for any advice. Please avoid providing answers in JQuery.

More code:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjGydw

Comment: just overwrite the double click event and make it do nothing?

Comment: @Steve Or `return false` for it.

Comment: @divy3993 I think return false only works for jQuery, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Steve My bad didn't see for no JQuery tag.

Comment: one approach is to disable the button until the action is complete, then re-enable it.

Comment: May I see an example please? Then I can mark the question solved. :D

Comment: @user2561920 can you provide a working example where dblclick has some effect, otherwise it's hard to prove that code prevents it

Comment: @Steve return false does a lot of things, you shouldn't be using it in jQuery.

Comment: @user2561920 there isn't enough information in the question to reproduce the problem. Voting to close.

Comment: How is there not enough information? Do you need to see a codepen or something? I've provided all the code that is relevant but ok..

Comment: Thank you for any useful suggestions for the concept of a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself, while the answer is more complex, is anyone is looking to apply listeners to disable the ability to doubleclick, it's here:

(arrowRight and arrowLeft are variables that have been defined by ID)

```
arrowRight.addEventListener('dblclick', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    });
    arrowLeft.addEventListener('dblclick', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I also created functions that disable the arrow while animation is happening to prevent errors. Reenables after animation completes. Functions look like this:

```
function disableArrows() { //ADDED NEW FUNCTION TO DISABLE ARROWS
    arrowRight.removeEventListener('click', onTopArrow, false);
    arrowLeft.removeEventListener('click', onBottomArrow, false);
}

function enableArrows() { //ADDED NEW FUNCTION TO RE-ENABLE ARROWS
    arrowRight.addEventListener('click', onTopArrow, false);
    arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', onBottomArrow, false);
}
```